# Immediate response after subscribtion

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

This is my theoretical service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  @Output() data: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.data.emit(Math.random());
    }, 1e3);
  }
}
```

And my component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.dataService.data.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Works good, I have new data when it comes.
But how to change my DataService to provide data immediately after subscription.
I mean, I want to store last data (in this theoretical case random number) and provide it right after subscription.
Is this even possible using rxjs?

Comment: Yes, that's called a `BehaviorSubject`. `@Output`s are Angular-related and should only be used with parent-child components.

Answer (score 3):

1. don't use event emitters in place of subjects, they are not guaranteed to always follow the observable contract
2. don't use an output in a service, it applies to components and directives only
3. use a behavior subject to have new subscribers immediately get the last emitted value upon subscription
4. good practice to make subjects private and expose a public observable

Like so:

```
 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class DataService {
   private data: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(null); // initialize to whatever
   data$: Observable<number> = this.data.asObservable();

   constructor() {
     setInterval(() => {
       this.data.next(Math.random()); // use next for subjects
     }, 1e3);
   }
 }
```

Comment: behavior subject is for storing / sending the last emitted value to new subscribers.

Comment: Thank you. Its working as I expected with initial null.
It have ```next``` method, not ```emit```